# How to capitalise the last alphabet of each word present in the string in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How you capitalise the last alphabet of each word present in the string in ruby?
For example:

Input String: the creator never dies
Output String Must Be: thE creatoR neveR dieS

Note: Length of the string is not constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty way is:

```
(s.reverse.split(" ").each {|w| w.capitalize!}).join(" ").reverse
```

- where `s` is your string

Comment: From answering whilst watching TV 8)

Answer (score 5):

`your_string.gsub(/\w\b/) { |s| s.capitalize }`

Comment: @dimuch compact and readable if you know regular expressions and Ruby procs. **Well done!** Ruby is such an elegant programming language.

Answer (score 1):

```
str.split.map do |word|
  word[-1] = word[-1].upcase
  word
end.join(' ')
```

That is - split the word at whitespace; form a new array of each word with the last character uppercased; join them back together